# Geographic Data - Australia R

Tags: r, geography

I have data where I have a series of postcodes and figures attached to them.

E.g.

```
Postcode         Value
2001           $51,000

2050       $21,001,000

3123        $3,200,000

4254        $6,500,000
```

For a variety of postcodes. How would I go about creating a heat map with these figures? I can only find mapping functions for American countries and counties or for other software.

EDIT: I apologise, as a form of censorship, the postcodes I listed were random numbers with a logical first digit. Don't look into them too closely.

Comment: You probably want to start with the ABS Postal Areas in ESRI shapefile format, which [can be found here](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202016?OpenDocument). Then search for a good tutorial about creating maps from shapefiles using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is not a complete answer, but since your question is pretty vague, and this wouldn't fit well into a comment, here it is)

You can use `ggmap` to return Google map search results as GPS coordinates. That should be a good start:

```
ggmap::geocode( paste( c( 2001, 2050, 3123, 4254 ), "Australia" ) )
```

Which returns:

```
        lon       lat
1 133.77514 -25.27440
2 151.17673 -33.88991
3 145.05209 -37.83108
4 -82.73975  27.99696
```

Pass these as the `x` and `y` coordinates on your mapping function.

EDIT: I'm noticing 4254 is returning a weird result. Where is that? I don't know the postcode, and Google doesn't seem to either.

Comment: Sorry about the postcodes, they were random numbers, not actual places. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! It's definitely worthwhile plotting just your location points here as a sanity check before going further with it. Google returns overly generic results when it can't find a match (as it's done here by putting  `2001` in central Australia).